# how to get selected row value in the KendoUI

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendoUI grid.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EntityVM>()
                    .Name("EntitesGrid")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:750px;width:100%;scrollbar-face-color: #eff7fc;" })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Id).Hidden().IncludeInMenu(false);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.EntityVersionId).Hidden().IncludeInMenu(false);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Name).Width("70%").Title("Entity Name");
                        columns.Bound(e => e.EIN).Width("30%");
                    })
        .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add' id='addEntity'><span class='k-icon k-add'></span>Entity</a>" +
             "<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' id='editEntity'><span class='k-icon k-edit'></span>Edit</a>"))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax().ServerOperation(false)
                    .Model(model => model.Id(e => e.Id))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetEntities", "Entity", new { projectId = Request.QueryString[DataKeyNameConstants.ProjectId] })))
                    .Sortable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .Filterable()
                    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                    .ColumnMenu()
                    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                    .Events(events => events.Change("entSelChange"))
            )
```

now, I need to get the value of EntityVersionId from the selected Row.  but not sure how to do it.

here's my javascript function

```
$("#editEntity").click(function () {

    var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    // what should I do from here
});
```

**UPDATE: add code to loop all rows.**

```
function loadPreviousEntityVersion() {

    alert("sdfsdfsdf");
    var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = entityGrid.dataSource.data();

    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var currentDataItem = data[i];
        alert(dataItem.EntityVersionId);

    }
}
```

Comment: Also wanted to point out that KendoUI's grid does support batch editing / adding since it looks like you *may* be hand rolling that same idea. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html

Answer (score 108, accepted):

One way is to use the Grid's [`select()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#select)  and [`dataItem()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem) methods.

In single selection case, `select()` will return a single row which can be passed to `dataItem()`

```
var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());
// selectedItem has EntityVersionId and the rest of your model
```

For multiple row selection `select()` will return an array of rows. You can then iterate through the array and the individual rows can be passed into the grid's `dataItem()`.

```
var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var rows = entityGrid.select();
rows.each(function(index, row) {
  var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(row);
  // selectedItem has EntityVersionId and the rest of your model
});
```

Comment: one last thing I'd like to point out is that selectedItem has the entire model that was eventually fetched by the DataSource, including properties which aren't used by a user control. For example. your EntityVersionId would be there even if it was not a hidden column.

Comment: thank you so much, I have another question. now if you need to loop through all rows, not just the one you selected. is there something like entityGrid.rows() to get all rows.  I cannot find it in the api.

Comment: If you need all the data and not the literal html rows, I wouldn't even bother with the grid's api. All dataItem() is doing is simplifying direct access to the dataSource underneath, so use that directly instead. entityGrid.dataSource.data() should give you everything. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your code, I need to use the selected rows as the data source of another grid, is it posible directly?

Answer (score 11):

There is better way. I'm using it in pages where I'm using kendo angularJS directives and grids has'nt IDs...

```
change: function (e) {
   var selectedDataItem = e != null ? e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select()) : null;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that if you jut click on the grid item it will trigger the event, while it suppose to only do ti when a changed really happened. Basically the functionality as per "edit"

Answer (score 4):

I think it needs to be checked if any row is selected or not?
The below code would check it:

```
var entityGrid = $("#EntitesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());
            if (selectedItem != undefined)
                alert("The Row Is SELECTED");
            else
                alert("NO Row Is SELECTED")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select particular element use below code

```
var gridRowData = $("<your grid name>").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = gridRowData.dataItem(gridRowData.select());
var quote = selectedItem["<column name>"];
```