# How to bind selected kendo grid rows to another kendo grid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have one kendo grid with check box options in popup window and one more empty kendo grid in the main view.What i need is to bind the selected checkbox rows in grid 1 to empty kendo grid in mvc

Answer (score 0):

Check the following post, which discusses a similar scenario:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707214/3086237

Even if you are not using the built-in selection feature, the core step is to retrieve a collection of the checked/selected rows in the first Grid via the `dataItem` method and push them to an array. Then, assign the array to the second Grid's dataSource instance.

An important note - the first Grid should use [Ajax binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding), otherwise there are no client-side data item instances.